# Shape preserving clamped ends interpolation in Matlab

Tags: matlab, interpolation

I'm looking for an algorithm in Matlab that can preserve the shape of my data while allowing me to clamp the ends. I'm trying to generate the camber line from the chord line, the leading edge angle, trailing edge angle, and the position of the max camber. See [Airfoil terminology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airfoil#Airfoil_terminology) for definitions. Using that information, I want to generate any number of points between the leading edge and the trailing edge, evenly spaced on the chord.

Here are the algorithms I've evaluated so far:

'pchip' doesn't seem to allow clamping, unless I mistyped repeatedly when searching, but does offer proper shape preservation.

'spline' doesn't preserve shape. Using 3 points of data, the middle data point being the max camber and both ends clamped, a spline can't guarantee the middle data to be the highest point on the generated curve. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9067095/1178317) for an example of that behavior.

'csape' provides adequate end conditions, but I cannot be sure it is adequately shape preserving.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've posted my question on the mathematics stack exchange and got the following [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/104331/24096). Essentially, I can use the Fritsch-Carlson scheme to calculate/set slopes at my data points. If I want to set the slope to my middle point, I will separate my interval in two parts, like Bill Cheatham suggests.

I can also wrap my data and use pchip or a spline for the points that apply instead of reimplementing the whole method.

Answer (score 0):

If your data will only ever have those three points, you can do it in two stages, one for the first half, and the next for the second half. You can use the fact that at the point furthest from the chord line (the middle point), the gradient of the line will be zero.

Generate each line as a spline between two points, with each end at the designated angle.

```
X = [0 5 10];
Y = [0 3 2];
start_slope = 0;
end_slope = -0.7;

xx1 = linspace(X(1), X(2), 100);
xx2 = linspace(X(2), X(3), 100);
yy1 = spline(X(1:2), [start_slope, Y(1:2), 0], xx1);
yy2 = spline(X(2:3), [0, Y(2:3), end_slope], xx2); 

plot([xx1, xx2],  [yy1, yy2]);
hold on
scatter(X, Y, 'filled')
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, it's almost exactly what I need. How would you generate an even number of evenly spaced points along the chord line? (No middle point duplication, of course)

Comment: The number 100 in the example above is the number of points generated for each section of the line. If your middle point isn't dead centre, you may have to play around with linspace to divide the points pro-rata between the two halves. Finally, remove the first point from yy2 to get rid of the duplication.

Comment: Oops! The spline overshoots. On your graph, at around 6, the value on the y axis is greater than that of the "top point". Also, point of interest, the axis can be the chord. Meaning Y = [0 3 0].

Comment: Hmmm... yes I suppose that is true, splines can bend the other way. It may be tough to overcome that. You want to enforce a slope >= 0 along the whole of the second half, and I'm not sure if that can be done using any of the built-in MATLAB interpolations.

Comment: hence my evaluation of 'pchip' as an interpolator, and 'csape'. I also think that a hard limit on the slope wouldn't define a proper airfoil.

Comment: I see... Well it's an interesting problem, I'll see if I have any more time to spend on it later, or else I'll keep an eye on any other answers!